# Get property value in List<> instead of [0],[1]

Tags: c#, list, dynamic

I am using a dynamic class to generate a list, however in the property ;ist I dont get the names as you get in a static class but [0],[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vO9ac.gif),[2], ect.
I need these names into the properties.

Anybody knows the (probably) simple answer?

here my code

UPDATE 1:

```
List<string> Properties = new List<string>();
        Properties.Add("name");
        Properties.Add("instituteTypeId");
        Properties.Add("city");
        Properties.Add("id");

List<DynamicClass> DynamicClassList = new List<DynamicClass>();

            int i = 0;
           foreach (DataRow r in _data.Rows)
           {
               DynamicClass dynamicClass = new DynamicClass();
            foreach (String Property in Properties)
              {
                dynamicClass.property[Property.ToString()] = _data.Rows[i][Property].ToString(); // private string RandomString(int size)
            }
            DynamicClassList.Add(dynamicClass);
}
```

My dynamic class is:

```
public class DynamicClass
{
    // property is a class that will create dynamic properties at runtime
    private DynamicProperty _property = new DynamicProperty();

    public DynamicProperty property
    {
        get { return _property; }
        set { _property = value; }
    }
}
public class DynamicProperty
{
    // a Dictionary that hold all the dynamic property values
    private Dictionary<string, object> properties = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    // the property call to get any dynamic property in our Dictionary, or "" if none found.
    public object this[string name]
    {
        get
        {
            if (properties.ContainsKey(name))
            {
                return properties[name];
            }
            return "";
        }
        set
        {
            properties[name] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Which should give me the same result as:

```
Medical data = new Medical();
data.Name = _data.Rows[i]["name"].ToString();
data.instituteTypeId = Convert.ToInt32(_data.Rows[i]["instituteTypeId"].ToString());
data.City = _data.Rows[i]["city"].ToString();
data.ID = Convert.ToInt32(_data.Rows[i]["id"].ToString());
list.Add(data);
```

UPDATE 2:

```
public class Medical
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public int instituteTypeId { get; set; }
}
```

If I look to the property on runtime from the DynamicClassList I see with the dynamic (sorry dont know how to upload image) something like this:

```
key   value
[0]   [{id,1}]
[1]   [{name, Med 1}]
```

While in the static Class it does correct as I need

```
key   value
[id]  {1}
[name] {Med 1}
```

[image]

From my point of view they are the same with the slide difference that with static I see the key values in the key field and with the dynamic in a [{key,value}]

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: No not that I care what I see in the viewer, but the jQuery object we use cares as it cannot select the proper value...

Comment: You are falling in to the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), if you are having a problem with building a JQuery object ***then ask about building a JQuery object***, not about how to get it to display correctly in the debugger. I would recommend deleting this question and asking a new question and be sure to include the bigger picture this time, say you are trying to convert to JQuery, include what you have tried, and show what Output you are getting and what output you expect.

Comment: http://imgur.com/OIiYQ0f

Comment: That is exactly what my code will do, but I have no idea if that will work with JQuery or not. You should ask about JQuery instead. (also I You can delete the old comments that are no longer relevant, I deleted mine)

Comment: No no issues to build the jQuery object, need to have a dynamic way to put the data into a Dynamic list, jQuery object works good

Comment: http://imgur.com/9shrhu6

Comment: the problem is in the key value, I need this somehow as a key, anyway to accomplish this?

Comment: You have not asked your question well so I have no idea what you are trying to accomplish. I would recommend opening a new question and explain thoroughly what you are trying to do from start to finish and what is not working with the way you are currently trying

Comment: I think its almost there, only difference is that the name is a string and not a key, which I cant figure out how to make it a key

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a [DebuggerTypeProxy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228992.aspx) and a few specialized classes.

```
public class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DynamicClass dynamicClass = new DynamicClass();
        dynamicClass.Property["Test"] = 1;
        dynamicClass.Property["test2"] = "foo";

        Debugger.Break();
    }
}


[DebuggerTypeProxy(typeof(DynamicClassProxy))]
public class DynamicClass
{
    // property is a class that will create dynamic properties at runtime
    private DynamicProperty _property = new DynamicProperty();

    public DynamicProperty Property
    {
        get { return _property; }
        set { _property = value; }
    }

    [DebuggerDisplay("{value}", Name = "{key}")]
    private class KeyValuePair
    {
        private string key;
        private object value;

        public KeyValuePair(KeyValuePair<string,object> kvp)
        {
            this.value = kvp.Value;
            this.key = kvp.Key;
        }
    }

    private class DynamicClassProxy
    {
        private DynamicClass _dynamicClass;
        public DynamicClassProxy(DynamicClass dynamicClass)
        {
            _dynamicClass = dynamicClass;
        }

        [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.RootHidden)]
        public KeyValuePair[] Keys
        {
            get
            {
                return _dynamicClass.Property.properties.Select(x => new KeyValuePair(x)).ToArray();
            }
        }
    }

    public class DynamicProperty
    {
        //Make it so no one can create these objects.
        internal DynamicProperty() { }

        // a Dictionary that hold all the dynamic property values
        internal Dictionary<string, object> properties = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        // the property call to get any dynamic property in our Dictionary, or "" if none found.
        public object this[string name]
        {
            get
            {
                if (properties.ContainsKey(name))
                {
                    return properties[name];
                }
                return "";
            }
            set
            {
                properties[name] = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE:** To remote the quotes around the key name add `nq` to the `Name` property.

```
[DebuggerDisplay("{value}", Name = "{key,nq}")]
private class KeyValuePair
{
    private object key;
    private object value;

    public KeyValuePair(KeyValuePair<string,object> kvp)
    {
        this.value = kvp.Value;
        this.key = kvp.Key;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Still does not work, somehow I need the Key as Key and wont accept a string, tested it with the static Class and works fine with this (as before)

Comment: And like I said, getting it to display in the debugger and getting it to work in jQuery is very very different. There is no such type called `Key` so I don't know how to make the Key of type `Key`. I recommend for a 3rd time, ask a new question specifically about getting your dynamic class to work with jQuery.

Comment: Scott, this is what my issue is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19283503/difference-between-key-and-key-and-value-versus-value-in-list-and-dictionary