# Difference between Key and _key and value versus Value in List and Dictionary

Tags: c#, list, c#-4.0, dictionary, key

Does anybody knows the different between Key and _key in the List<> and Dictionary, how to approach them and manipulate them?

Comment: Your question is unclear.

Comment: Where do you see `_key` ??

Comment: for example: imgur.com/OIiYQ0f

Comment: or this with normal keys: http://imgur.com/9shrhu6

Comment: They are backing-fields for the public exposed properties and why would you want to manipulate them?

Comment: Because if I make a Dynamic list (read Dynamic Class) for a jqGrid autocomplete apparantly I need these Key and not the _key, so try to figure out how theses things are working and why with dynamic class they dont show up and in a static Class they do....

Comment: I have made a dynamic class for a list which works fine, however it has one small difference between a static list and dynamic the dynamic uses the _key and static the Key (which I need). breaking my neck on this for the past few days and nobody seems to being able to have a solving answer on this

Comment: You're missing the point of my question. What is it that you're trying to achieve and I don't mean world peace, but I do mean a bigger picture in general like what do you want these lists/dictionaries to do?

Comment: Simple that the Dynamic Classes are using the Key instead of the _key. In a previous post the explaination did not went well, however contains some code I am using: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19227806/get-property-value-in-list-instead-of-0-1?lq=1

Comment: The problem is I dont want or can hardcore code the Classes for the strong key so need to do this dynamic

Comment: What is unclear about the question, why downgrade, if you dont know the concept of strong keys in the List<>, dont comment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your question and examples, I'm guessing you are enumerating a collection of `DictionaryEntry` structures.  If that is the case, `_key` is a private member variable and `Key` is a public property.  You can access `Key` from your code because it is public, but not `_key` because it is private.

The debugger is able to show you both values via reflection.  You should only use the `Key` property in your code.

Comment: ok that explains the difference, but not why I can't set the Public Key with my dynamic Class and it just shows up into the private _key, also explains why the jQuery autocomplete does not function without it )))

Comment: Can you add the representative code for your dynamic class to your question?  Seeing some code may help see what's happening.